# Trying to call a method inside a controller for binding dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bind a dropdown by calling a method inside an action method inside a controller.

```
public ActionResult Ipcell(Int id)
{
List<string> ddltype = bindtype();
}
private List<string> bindtype()
{
    List<Ipcell> result = new List<Ipcell>();
    conn.Open();
    string qry = "select icd_type from SE_DTLS";
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(qry, conn);
    OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader != null && reader.Read())
    {
        Ipcell member = new Ipcell();
        member.CaseId = reader[0].ToString();
        member.Type = reader[1].ToString();
        result.Add(member);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

`Ipcell` is a model class
but getting error at return `result.ToString();`

> "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List
> to system.collections.Generic.List".

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: The error is being displayed due to the last line. You can't convert Ipcell to string

Comment: @Kaveesh i remove the t string but now getting eror "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<smartmis.Models.Ipcell.> to system.collections.Generic.List<string>".

Comment: Your return type of the function is List<string>. Even if you change that you will get next error in List<string> ddltype = bindtype();. If you actually need a list of strings I suggest you convert the object of Ipcell to string, Not the whole List, albeit a new List of strings based on content in Ipcell . Something like orig.ConvertAll(x => new TargetType { SomeValue = x.SomeValue }); Otherwise, change the ddlType to List<Ipcell> and return as List<Ipcell>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly convert `List<Ipcell>` to `List<string>` by calling `.ToString()`

You need to set the return type of the function `bindType()` to `List<Ipcell>`. With this, you will also need to change the type of `ddltype` to `List<Ipcell>` for your code to compile correctly.

You can later use the values inside `Ipcell` (`Ipcell.CaseId` and `Ipcell.Type`) for your binding purpose.